# mysql & php - update int column with a quotient already converted to an int leaves me with numerator or zero

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

**Please see the updates below!**

This is what I want to do: Get the last update timestamp (stored as int) of an article, together with the popularity at the time of the last update (also int), calculate the new popularity and the resulting trend (= an estimate for the change of the popularity per time unit since the last update) and update the article.

The problem is, the value that gets written to the DB row is almost always either the numerator of the trend equation (so the calculated popularity) or 0. Static values for the popularity don't change a thing, however static values for last_update or time() result in the right value being inserted. Something else that's strange: Leaving last_update out of the update query also results in the right value for trend to be inserted. It's like the last_update column affects the trend column, I don't understand how.

This is my code, please note I'm using codeigniter so I used activerecord for getting the article. Plus I used intval() for nearly all numeric values because my first guess was a datatype problem:

```
$this->db->where('id', 1);
$article_query = $this->db->get('articles');
$article = $article_query->row_array();

$article['last_update'] = intval($article['last_update']);
$time = intval(time());
$new_popularity = // Calculate Popularity here (I tried with static values, doesn't affect the result) ;
$time_diff = intval(($time - $article['last_update']));

$trend = intval((($new_popularity - $article['popularity']) / $time_diff)); 

var_dump($trend);

$this->db->query('UPDATE `articles` SET `popularity` = '.$new_popularity.',  `trend` = '.$trend.' WHERE `id` =  1 ');
```

The var dump gives me an int with the expected value. The query log also shows the expected query, something like

```
UPDATE `articles` SET `popularity` = 50000, `last_update` = 1374840645, `trend` = 10 WHERE `id` =  1
```

But 50000 gets inserted for trend. As mentioned before, static values for $time and $article['last_update'] make the problem go away, so does leaving the last_update out of the query. I also tried ceil(), floor(), casting (int) on every single value, nothing works.

All the involved columns are int(11), which should be big enough. I also tried varchar for trend and inserting it as a string - no success. I have been dealing with this problem for 2 days and I'm really desperate for any help!

I'm running MySQL 5.5.32 on Windows 7.

Please make the weirdness go away, thank you!

**edit:** to clarify further: For testing purposes I set $article['popularity'] to 0, so I could test repeatedly and still get a trend >0. That's why 50000 got inserted and not the actual difference.

**update:** this is where my code is now. Set last_update to TIMEZONE type with ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

```
$this->db->where('id', 1);
$article_query = $this->db->get('articles');
$article = $article_query->row_array();

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$article['last_update'] = intval(strtotime($article['last_update']));

$time = intval(time());
$new_popularity = 50000; // Static test value
$time_diff = intval(($time - $article['last_update']));

$trend = intval((($new_popularity - 0) / $time_diff)); // Zero for testing purposes only, so that there will always be a positive trend.

var_dump($trend);

$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
$this->db->query('UPDATE articles SET popularity = ?,  trend = ? WHERE id =  ?', Array($new_popularity, $trend, 1));
```

Query log:

```
UPDATE articles SET popularity = 50000, trend = 403 WHERE id =  1
```

Actual values via phpMyAdmin: popularity = 50000, trend = 50000. I'm also running the code on a clean install of apache and mysql now, with php 5.4.15, mysql 5.6.11. Next I'll try without codeigniter alltogether I guess...

**UPDATE**: My own mistake, I didn't read the log very carefully and didn't notice something like this occuring:

```
130730 17:25:48    51 Connect   root@localhost on zeenr
           51 Init DB   zeenr
           51 Query SET NAMES utf8
           51 Query SET SESSION sql_mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"
           51 Query SELECT *
FROM (`articles`)
WHERE `id` =  1
           51 Query UPDATE articles SET `popularity` = 50000, `trend` = 179 WHERE `id` =  1
           51 Quit  
130730 17:25:49    52 Connect   root@localhost on zeenr
           52 Init DB   zeenr
           52 Query SET NAMES utf8
           52 Query SET SESSION sql_mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"
           52 Query SELECT *
FROM (`articles`)
WHERE `id` =  1
           52 Query UPDATE articles SET `popularity` = 50000, `trend` = 50000 WHERE `id` =  1
           52 Quit
```

Why is it happening? I have no loop whatsoever in my code.

Comment: if you run the query directly in PHPMyAdmin, does it work?

Comment: yes, without a problem. that's why I was thinking datatype problem, maybe some invisible characters, but intval should fix that I think

Comment: so the query log is from codeigniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To really know what query is run you should enable the MySql log:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

After running the query there is a logfile in `C:\xampp\mysql\data`. (in my case)

Also try without protecting identifiers and with query bindings:

```
$this->db->query(
    'UPDATE articles SET popularity = ?, trend = ? WHERE id = ?',
    array($new_popularity, $trend, 1)
);
```

EDIT:

Have you tried the [active record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update) syntax?

```
$data = array
(
    'popularity' => $new_popularity,
    'trend' => $trend,
);

$this->db->where('id', 1);
$this->db->update('articles', $data);
```

Comment: That was already the query log I was referring to! Your solution really works! Thank you so much! I still wonder what the problem was though?

Comment: are you sure the query log that you posted was from the codeigniter query? I guess the problem was that you manually added the protecting identifiers and codeigniter messed it up. But since I do not know codeigniter I can only guess.

Comment: I had the same problem with relying completely on ActiveRecord which generates the query automatically, but testing without protecting identifiers proofed to be the correct answer. I'm not entirely sure what happened there, probably going to read a little bit of CI man now :) I'm really grateful for you help! Thank you so much!

Comment: OK damnit. I made a mistake and inserted $article['last_update'] instead of $time in last_update. With $time it didn't work :( What in gods name is wrong with this script

Comment: @daga what exactly doesn't work? Can you update your question with actual code and query log? You also should consider to change `last_update` to a `TIMESTAMP` type with `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attribute. In this way you don't have to include it in the query.

Comment: The same error persists. I tried various things now. The last_update field seems to be the problem, even if I write a rand() to it and not a timestamp it will break the trend column. I will try changing it to TIMESTAMP now, thank you. I even tried seperating the last_update UPDATE to its own query, but I guess automatic optimization treats it as 1 query because the same errors occur.. Thank you for still replying!

Comment: Okay, I changed the column as you suggested and took last_update out of my update query (because it updates by itself like supposed to). vardump on trend is still something like int(1574), inserted value still 0. Funny thing now: My timezone was set to UTC at first, so I got a negative value as $time_diff, and a negative trend that was updated correctly...? Will update my question soon with code and new query log.

Comment: if you use `TIMESTAMP` type you'll get the value as string `Y-m-d H:i:s` out of database. So you have to use `strtotime($article['last_update'])` to convert it to integer time. Also see my update..

Comment: Yes that's what I did, see my update for current code! I actually used the active record syntax before I noticed my little error, and chose to write the query myself for better control. But trying doesn't hurt considering a few things changed!

Comment: No success, sadly. I'll try without the framework now (wonder why I didn't try that earlier). If it works then, maybe that's enough encouragement to get my lazy ass to move on to another framework :)

Comment: if this really is your query log, then some other strange stuff is going on. Is there a trigger on the table for example?

Comment: oh its just the query, sorry. I don't really have experience reading it. Posting the full log now. Tried a script using nothing but PDO now, same error.

Comment: Okay, my inexperience reading this thing and me thinking I could manage by myself was a grave mistake, you would've catched it earlier. See update in a minute. Still have no solution though.

Comment: ok this shows clearly that the error is somewhere else in the script..I don't know the whole context, but there is perhaps a redirect involved which fires the update again?

Comment: OK, I got it. Really funny story: It was the .htaccess file for the URL rewrite. Contents: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] --- I don't know why it caused the redirect, but at least I know the source of the problem. I can't upvote you enough for sticking with me! Thank you a lot! Seems like it was a type problem after all - The same .htaccess rewritten - no problems.

Comment: yeah..nice to hear that. sometimes programming can be frustrating, but the error always sits in front of the screen ;)

Comment: Seems like it was a type problem after all - The same .htaccess rewritten - no problems. Always mind those invisible characters! Haha yes, that's true.. One last question: Are you native german, because I'm native austrian and we could've spoken german all along ;)

Comment: ja, ich komme aus Köln..tja beim nächsten Mal ;)

Comment: Auf jeden Fall, schönen Abend noch!